# Casting a variable of generic data type to String in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, type-conversion

I have a generic class which contains a variable of generic data type. I need to convert this variable to String.

Example Code -

```
class test<T> {
var value:T!
var name: String!

  init(text: String, val: T)
  {
    name = text
    value = val
  }

  func toString() -> String {
    let temp = value as! String
    //let temp = String(value)
    return name + ": " + temp 
  }
}
```

I tried down-casting it by doing *let temp = value as! String* but it leads to crash during run time

Doing `let temp = String(value)` throws Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(T?)' build error

Comment: the crash won't happen if you specify T as String , can you show creation of test ?

Comment: T is going to be Int or Float in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use String interpolation to include `value` in a String.

```
class Test<T> {
    var value:T
    var name: String

    init(text: String, val: T) {
        name = text
        value = val
    }

    func toString() -> String {
        return "\(name): \(value)"
    }
}
```

Unrelated to your issue, but don't declare any of your variables as implicitly unwrapped Optionals (`!` after their type), especially not when you are setting them in the initializer. You should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is UpperCamelCase for types (`Test`).